# oj-table row grouping and row selection type checkbox

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, oracle-jet

I have below requirement. I only need to use oracle-jet **oj-table**:

- On page load organization data is loaded with different roles of
  employees. Need to bind this data to oj-table, with rows grouped on
  employee role (like manager, HR etc..)
- Row selection should be enabled with checkbox in first column. Single
  & multiple selection needed.
- Group header row should also have the checkbox, selecting which
  selects all the employees in that group.

Sample code or examples or any reference links are highly appriciated.

Thanks

Comment: After working for 6 months on oracle jet, I feel better not to use oracle jet framework, instead use react or angular or even plain html css javascript.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of example in [Oracle JET cookbook](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jetCookbook.html) on how to bind data to an `oj-table`.

For checking one/all rows, here is one way to do it:

View:

```
<oj-table data="[[ dataProvider ]]" columns='[{"headerText": "Check All", "headerTemplate": "headerTpl", "resizable": "enabled", "sortable": "disabled", "template": "checkTpl"}]'>
  <template slot="headerTpl" data-oj-as="cell">
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: bulkCheckFlag" />
  </template>
  <template slot="allactivechkbox" data-oj-as="cell">
    <input type="checkbox" name="selectedIds" data-bind="attr:{value:cell.row.ID, id:cell.row.ID}" />
  </template>
</οj-table>
```

Model:

```
class ViewModel {
  constructor() {
    const self = this;
    this.dataProvider = yourDataProviderSetup();
    this.bulkCheckFlag = ko.observable(false);
    this.bulkCheckFlag.subscribe((newValue) => {
      $("input[name='selectedIds']").prop("checked", newValue);
    }
    this.selectedIds = () => $("input[name='selectedIds']:checked").toArray().map((el) => el.id));
}
```

If you have a button or something, you can then have a click callback where you can have your selected IDs by `const ids = self.selectedIDs();`.

Note that there are probably better ways to do this, but, in summary:

- One checkbox for each row, with the same name (`selectedIds` in the example) and each of them having the ID of the entity represented by that row;
- One checkbox in column header, which has a flag in the ViewModel as `Observable<boolean>`, subscribe to its value and update the value of all checkboxes with the above name (`selectedIds`);
- One method to select those checked checkboxes and retrieve their IDs when needed.

**EDIT:**
There is a [Cookbook example](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jetCookbook.html?component=table&demo=selectionTable) for (multi)selection, which is waaaaay easier than my hacky approach.